# how to like chatter comments

Tags: apex, chatter, connect-api

How can I use the ConnectAPI to like a chatter comment? I'm looking at the likeFeedItem method in the ChatterFeeds class. How do I get the FeedItemId? I'm not seeing a method to get the FeedItemId?

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple API to like chatter feed..

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_likeComment

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_likeFeedElement

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_likeFeedItem

Answer (score 1):

A feed contains a collection of feed elements. If you get a feed with something like [ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_getFeedElementsFromFeed_2)(communityId, ConnectApi.FeedType.News, 'me'), the result have a collection of feed elements, and each feed element will have an "id" property -- that's the ID to use in the likeFeedItem or likeFeedElement method call.